# Loading components on splash screen

Tags: c#, winforms

This might be a primitive question but I really like to get more information. I have seen many professional programs have a splash screen and during that a progress bar and some text indicating that program is loading...

I want to know what CAN or SHOULD be loaded during such time? Do they load classes or something? I am noob and do not know what requires loading before a program actually starts.

Comment: In my experience I only use a loading icon or progress bar when there is some return that takes some time to process.  I use it more as a mechanism to let the end user know the app hasn't locked up.

Comment: I'm in agreement with Brian.  A splash/loading screen should only be used to indicate to the user that a long-running operation is taking place.  If there's no long-running op, then a splash screen just delays the user from getting in there and using you app.  Bad.

Comment: isn't that where you wish the user happy birthday? or show some fancy animation? its depends on the application - business app's load repositories and business objects (fetch stuff from dB), 3D app's eager load many of the objects required for matrix operations, games eager load the graphics, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, yes. They load classes.

If the program's design is modular enough, the outer shell can be small enough to run almost immediately on most devices (think mobile phones here) and display a progress bar while loading behavior (features provided by external modules, [assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173099.aspx) in C#) in the background.

However, that's not always the best approach to program loading. If your user interface can be up and running in less than five seconds on a typical client machine, it may not even be worth a progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

Well it depends on the program. I use a loading screen when my game is randomly generating terrain which can take anywhere between 1 second to 2 minutes.